# What to do when integration boundary is on pole.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

What to do when integration boundary is on pole. I want to integrate $(dx/x)\log(x-1)$ from $0$ to, lets say, "$a$", where "$a$" is arbitrary $a>1$, $a\le 2$. $x$ is real.

Answer (score 1):

This integral will diverge, because $\log(x-1)/x \approx \log(-1)/x$ as $x \to 0$ and $\int_0^a dx/x$ diverges.

Comment: What about if the integrand is just log(x-1)?

Comment: @Potato: $\int_0^1\log(x)\;\mathrm{d}x=-1$; that is, the integral converges near $0$.

Comment: Right. I think the asker may be mistaken and have meant that. I'm not sure.

Comment: $\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}$ has a removable singularity at $0$, but that is not a pole.